# Visual Studio Could Not Find File bin/debug/guid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting the error `Could not find file 'c:\...\visual studio 2015\Projects\Redacted\Redacted\bin\Debug\292122-OxcRPNQVMslxRTqnC9U0GA&since=2000-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00'`

That GUID of a file name, the file does not exist in that folder. I have no idea why it would.  I don't know what that file would be.

I tried creating a new consoleApplication with the same code and got the same error.

The error is being triggered by this line of code:

```
Dim client As New WebClient()
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
client.DownloadFile("https://export.yammer.com/api/v1/export?model=Message&include=csv&access_token=" & System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(accessToken) & "&since=" & WebUtility.UrlEncode("2000-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"), "C:\temp\yammer-messages.zip")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Need more info on the project, but that does not appear to be a GUID, but  (maybe) a url in a filename?  292122-OxcRPNQVMslxRTqnC9U0GA&since=2000-01-01T00:00:00+00:00, part of the string is since 1/1/2000 if you look at it.

Comment: In the solution itself, are there any broken references to file you're seeing?

Comment: @JimmySmith I added a code snippet of the line that triggers the error.  Does that help clarify the issue?

Comment: It does help a LOT.  Have you verified that there is a file located at, "https://export.yammer.com/api/v1/export?model=Message&include=csv&access_token=" & System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(accessToken) & "&since=" & WebUtility.UrlEncode("2000-01-01T00:00:00+00:00")  I'd just put a watch over this piece, then copy and paste the url to a browser

Comment: Wait, is this error while it's running or you go to compile?  Initially I was thinking it was during compile, but you're able to step through this program till it reaches `client.DownloadFile`...?

Comment: @JimmySmith I thought it was during compile too.  Then, I stepped through it just now, and got to the client.DownloadFile line.

Comment: @JImmySmith your suggestion to test the URL that is built was spot on.  There was a fat-fingered value in the url.

Comment: I've been there before.  Glad this helped you out!